# Better content administration, sort by node's CCK fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, administration

I was asking myself if there's a better way of sorting content in Drupal.
Right now, when I go to admin>content all the nodes are mixed up. I installed the module "Content administration" (http://drupal.org/project/nodeadmin) and now you can not only filter but also sort them by title, type, author... but that's all.

Is there any good module to improve the content administration a part from the one I mentioned?
For instance, it would be great if I could filter the nodes by their CCk field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to improve the content AI, is to build your own with views and views bulk operations. With it, you can run tasks on many nodes at once, like publish/unpublish and you get all the views filtering / display options you have in any view.

Comment: Can I show that view as an admin menu item in the menu only visible for admins?
I mean, I know you can create the item and all that but I want to double-check is not accessible for everyone via a direct link whatsoever...

Comment: You can set permissions for a view by editing the "access" section of the basic settings of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout http://drupal.org/project/improved_admin - does basically what googletorp suggests for you.